# how do i make a combo box item show what is set to the master combo box?

Tags: combobox

this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.customer_Info_DataSet.Customer);

this.termsTableAdapter.Fill(this.terms_DataSet.Terms);

Customer_name is the display member of customer_Info_DataSet in the customer combo box and terms is the display member of the terms_DataSet in the terms combo box.  once the terms is set to the customer and saved to the data table it will not display on the form when the customer is displayed again.  how do I set this so that the terms combo box doesn't just show blank but show the term that is set for the customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had not properly bound the table to the form.  this means that the choices would show in the control but they weren't available when the text box was saved.  it was actually empty in the table that was to actually save the info.